# put image left of the text without this staircase effect

Tags: css

I have a list menu (`ul->li`) with I want to put images on the left **and center text in front of it**.

The problem is it creates and staircase using `float:left`.

What should I change?

http://jsfiddle.net/5ok9xbu9/

```
ul.list img{
   float:left;
   display:table;
   border-radius:10px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud change `<img>` to `<li>`

**CSS**

```
ul.list li{
 text-align:left;
 display:block;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ok9xbu9/4/)**

Comment: oh, I forget to mention, I want one li below the other!

Comment: Change to `display:block`, remove the `float:left`and add `text-align:left`

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/5ok9xbu9/2/)

CSS

```
ul.list img{
 float:left;
 border-radius:10px;
}

ul li
{
    float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="us"><img src="img/img.gif" width="30" class="" alt="img"></a>text</li>
    <li><a href="us"><img src="img/img.gif" width="30" class="" alt="img"></a>text</li>
    <li><a href="us"><img src="img/img.gif" width="30" class="" alt="img"></a>text</li>
    <li><a href="us"><img src="img/img.gif" width="30" class="" alt="img"></a>text</li>
    <li><a href="us"><img src="img/img.gif" width="30" class="" alt="img"></a>text</li>
    <li><a href="us"><img src="img/img.gif" width="30" class="" alt="img"></a>text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry, I forget to mention, I want one li below the other!